# Why type.__base__ is object but object.__class__ is type?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I run following codes in Jupyter console(Python's version is `2.7.14`):

```
type.__base__
Out[2]: object

object.__class__
Out[3]: type
```

It seems a puzzle to me. The base class of `type` is `object` but the class of `object` is `type`! **There's a circle.**

I've tried another codes as below,

```
class B(object): pass

class A(B): pass

A.__base__
Out[8]: __main__.B

B.__class__
Out[9]: type
```

There is none circle between A and B obviously. And I don't understand why there is a circle when talking about `type` and `object`.

---

**Update**:

Yes, everything's class is a type. But I want to know how to explain that `type.__class__` is `type` itself.

Comment: everything's class is a type

Answer (score 0):

Because `object` is a type, `object.__class__` should be `type`.

And since `type` itself is a class, it's inherited from `object`.

Look at these two examples to have a clearer sight:

```
>>> type.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> object.__base__
>>>
```

So, `object.__base__` is None.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I know what you have said. What I want to understand is `type.__class__` is `type` itself. How it is to be explained? How it is implemented?

Comment: @ShawnXie Python is implemented in C where everything goes beneath the surface. I don't know that deep, sorry.